# window.opener !== window returns false in child window when targeted as "_self" only in Mozilla, but works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have opened a child window from parent window using window.open as targeted "*_self*", when I try to `console.log(window.opener !== window)` in child window it return false in **Mozilla**, but works fine and return *true* in *chrome*.

What I want is the reference of the original parent window instance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
        wnd.document.write(
          "blank\<script\>alert(window.opener !== window)\</script\>"
        );
        console.log(wnd);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What you didn't get in the question?

Comment: What didn’t _you_ get of what is explained on those two pages I just referred you to? Without you showing us what you actually did, we can’t tell if you simply did something wrong.

Comment: Bro, the description is self explanatory.

Comment: Can you put a full example of both the code that opens the window, plus the child window testing for the condition mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

As per [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener#Notes)

> #### Usage notes
>
> When a window is opened from another window (using
>   Window.open or a link with its target attribute set), it maintains a
>   reference to that first window as window.opener. If the current window
>   has no opener, this method returns null.

So i'd expect `window.open` targeting self to be `null` and therefore

> window.opener !== window // true

either it is a bug or intended - there seems to be no consent in FF68.0.1 and Chrome75.0.3770.142

as a workaround mock an `_opener` ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        window._opener = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
       window._opener.document.write(
          "blank\<script\>alert(window._opener !== window)\</script\>"
        );
        
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I want is the refernce of the parent window in the child window

Comment: @AayushMittal until now i was sure that they both share one `window` object/reference - but tbh you can still wnd.parent = window ? cant you? pls explain what is not working? in which version? for me both your issue and my example are fine

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Examples):

> If a window with the name already exists, then `strUrl` is loaded into the existing window. In this case the return value of the method is the existing window and `strWindowFeatures` is ignored. Providing an empty string for `strUrl` is a way to get a reference to an open window by its name without changing the window's location.

So when you do

```
window.open(url, '_self');
```

you are actually only setting your current's window to this `url`, but the Window object doesn't change.

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  const wnd = window.open('', '_self'); // let's not change the url
  console.log(window === wnd);
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

So what your snippet is doing is really just updating your current document:

```js
function myFunction() {
  window.document.write(
    "blank\<script\>alert(window.opener !== window)\</script\>"
  );
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

---

However, the strange bit is that Firefox does update the `openedWindow.opener` to whatever window will call `window.open()` with its name.
[This is indeed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350858), and is what's ultimately causing your issue, since it should have stayed to whatever it was before (`null` in your example snippet).

---

But note that the core of you are trying to do (get "the reference of the original parent window instance"), is irrelevant here, since **there is always only one Window** in your snippet.

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is the refernece of the parent window in "child window". What you have suggested "var originalWindow = window" in the child window will give the refernce of the child window itself not the parent window.

Comment: No read again my answer. **There is no child window.** Both `wnd` and the main `window` are the same object.

Comment: But my requirement is to open a childwindow using window.open as _self

Comment: Well do it. But trying to retrieve the `opener` is useless since it is actually your current `window`.